# Use different Login page for AdminLTE

Tags: redirect, authentication, laravel-5.3, adminlte

I used [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) for Laravel 5.3. But i want to use my login page with connect to we server.
When i replace my code with auth/login.blade.php page, when i put my username and password and connect to web service, after get response from we server, i try to redirect to another page with `window.location.href = "/AddStudent";`. but page refresh and stay in login page. How must i do? which setting must i change?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="FileOfLogin/css/style.css">

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

        <form class="form">
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button id="loginsubmit" type="button" id="login-button">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul class="bg-bubbles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="FileOfLogin/js/index.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery 2.1.3 -->
<script src="{{ asset ("/bower_components/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.3.min.js") }}"></script>

<!-- Sweet Alarm -->
<script src="SweetAlert/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SweetAlert/sweetalert.css">


<script type="text/javascript">

    $( "#loginsubmit" ).click(function() {

        console.log('111');
        var username=$('#username').val();
        var password=$('#password').val();

        // console.log(username);
        // console.log(password);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://79.132.212.50:8080/SchoolServiceWebService/login",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: '{  "username": "'+username+'", "password": "'+password+'"  }',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (GetResult) {
                //  console.log(GetResult);
                if (GetResult.result) {
                    console.log(GetResult);
                    console.log("8888888888888");
                     window.location.href = "/AddStudent";
                    // window.location.replace('/AddStudent');
                } else {
                    sweetAlert("خطا", "ورود !!!!!!", "error");
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })//ajax

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to override the methods in "Auth\LoginController". This way, you can specify your own view and redirect to a custom page. For more information about Laravel Authentication Mechanism, check [this oficial page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users)